# what is the convergence domain of this series (including endpoints)

Tags: calculus

Could anyone help me with finding the convergence radius and convergence domain including endpoints of the following series:
$\Sigma_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(x+1)^{n+2}}{lnn}$

Thank you!

Comment: I suppose that the summation starts at $n=2$

Comment: yes.. thank you! corrected

Comment: The correction is worse !!!

Comment: oops.. sorry...! changing again.......

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n = \dfrac{(x+1)^{n+2}}{lnn}$ then use ratio test: $R = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} |\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = |x+1|$, and the series converges if and only if $R < 1$, and this means that $|x + 1| < 1$ or $-2 < x < 0$. The endpoints are: $x = -2$ and $x = 0$.

Case 1: $x = -2$, then $a_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{ln}$. The series converges conditionally.

Case 2: $x = 0$, then $a_n = \dfrac{1}{lnn}$. The series diverges since $a_n > \dfrac{1}{n}$

Comment: Thank you! though, I am used to $a_n = \frac{1}{lnn}$. Will get the same answer. It is not exactly clear to me how to work with $a_n = \dfrac{(x+1)^{n+2}}{lnn} $